# BluetoothPairingStateProvider: getUuids() returns null for device

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, fido-u2f, fido

**Context:**

I am working on a FIDO-U2F bluetooth authenticator with a nRF52 BLE SoC. and want it to test with [google example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-fido).

So far I have implemented the [FIDO Bluetooth specification](https://fidoalliance.org/specs/fido-u2f-v1.2-ps-20170411/fido-u2f-bt-protocol-v1.2-ps-20170411.html) and I have a device that advertises as a FIDO-compatible device.

Thanks to [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Software-and-Tools/Development-Tools/nRF-Connect-for-desktop) I have ensured that all the services and characteristics are correctly exposed and that I can interact with it only when my device is securely paired (with LTK):
[image: nRF Connect screenshot]

**Problem:**

When the app scans for eligible FIDO device, it does not find mine.

I am stuck on the screen that ask to press a button for 5s, which I don't need to since my device responds to pairing request without user interaction and is already paired with my SAMSUNG A8.

```
I/BluetoothDevicePreference: onDeviceAttributesChanged :: Device = (N) D8BE86, isBonded = 12 , mIsOnProgressAddVI = false
I/Fido: [BleScanner] startScan()
E/Fido: [BluetoothPairingStateProvider] getUuids() returns null for device: D8:BE:86:4A:E5:65
I/Fido: [PreferredTransportProvider] BLE enabled but no device is paired
I/Fido: [AuthenticateBaseChimeraActivity] User selected transport ble
I/Fido: [ViewController] Accepting proposed view {"viewName":"ble_instructions","anyU2fDevicesPaired":false}: outranks current (2 > 0)
I/Fido: [ViewPresenter] viewSelected(...) ble_instructions
I/Fido: [U2fRequestController] onResultReceived(null, ErrorResponseData{errorCode=5})
I/Fido: [BleScanner] stopScan()
```

I tried to remove pairing data and all I have is:

```
I/BluetoothDevicePreference: onDeviceAttributesChanged :: Device = (N) D8BE86, isBonded = 10 , mIsOnProgressAddVI = false
```

The advertising flags are currently set to "*BR/EDR not supported*", but I also tried "*LE Limited Discoverable Mode*" and "*LE General Discoverable Mode*" without success.

I looked into *android-fido* sources but the BLE scan seems imported from elsewhere, I cannot debug it in this project.

Any pointer is welcome

Answer (score 0):

Have you got to this screen?

[image]

We may need to add Service Data field (0x16) into advertising packet. This is mentioned in FIDO specification [here](https://fidoalliance.org/specs/fido-v2.0-id-20180227/fido-client-to-authenticator-protocol-v2.0-id-20180227.html#ble-pairing-authnr-considerations)

Android code snippet for advertising with Service Data field added:

```
AdvertiseData data = new AdvertiseData.Builder()
                        .addServiceUuid(new ParcelUuid(fido2GattService.getUuid()))
                        .setIncludeDeviceName(true)
                        .addServiceData(new ParcelUuid(fido2GattService.getUuid()), new byte[] {(byte)192, (byte)192, (byte)192})
                        .build();
```

If you want to capture bluetooth packets to see what is your advertising packet, you can use PacketLogger (for MacOS)

Here is the screenshot of the advertising packet
[image]

The red box is Service Data

Comment: I don't have this particular screen but something similar. Thanks for your suggestion. I moved to an other project but I'll get you a feedback when I'm back on this issue !